# Make barcode “foots” reach the text baseline

Tags: pst-barcode

With the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(3.5,3)
    \psbarcode{3-88309-455}{includetext}{isbn}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I get a barcode like this:

[image]

So, it’s a little bit anoying, because I want the guard bars (left, middle, and right) reach the base line of the bottom numbers or go over like this:

[image]

So, is there an option in `\pstbarcode` to force the guard lines to be longer than default behavior?

Comment: The first image is missing. Also, it seems the default behavior is 'correct', compare for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcode.

Comment: So yes, but I search to get an *incorrect* rendering and I assume it.

Answer (score 2):

The postscript code for producing the barcode images is located in the file `pst-barcode.pro` which is found in your TEXMF tree in `/dvips/pst-barcode`. You can copy this file to the directory of your document and then the `pst-barcode` package will load the local file instead of the system file.

Modify the following lines in the `ean13` encoder (starting at line 1165 in my version of `pst-barcode`):

```ps
includetext {
        /bhs [height height 12{height .075 sub}repeat height height 12{height .075 sub}repeat height height] def
        /bbs [0 0 12{.075}repeat 0 0 12{.075}repeat 0 0] def
    }
```

into the following:

```ps
includetext {
        /bhs [2{height 0.1 add}repeat 12{height .075 sub}repeat 2{height 0.1 add}repeat 12{height .075 sub}repeat 2{height 0.1 add}repeat] def
        /bbs [-0.1 -0.1 12{.075}repeat -0.1 -0.1 12{.075}repeat -0.1 -0.1] def
    }
```

Make sure you modify the right lines, there are a lot of similar lines for other encoders but this is the one for `ean13` which is used by the `isbn` encoder.

Explanation (note this may be wrong, I don't know Postscript at all): the `bhs` line controls the length of the bars. It starts with two bars of length `height`, then twelve bars of length `height-0.075`, then two normal bars, etc. The second line controls the baseline of the lines, which is 0 for the first two, 0.075 for the next twelve, etc. So all you need to do is increase the length of the long bars (with the `0.1 add` instruction) and lower the baseline (to -0.1 in the example).

Result:

[image]

It might be possible to patch the code on the fly (similar to `etoolbox`/`xpatch`) instead of copying and modifying the file, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: What is the command to find the local path of package in Unix? It seams to be `latexdef` but I can’t find yet a local copy of `pst-barcode`.

Comment: The command is `kpsewhich pst-barcode.sty` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1138/). You can also look in the terminal output or in the log file of your document to see the full path of each package used. Note that `pst-barcode` has a bit of a complex file structure, there is `pst-barcode.sty` which is a boilerplate package that loads `pst-barcode.tex` which is a frontend for `pst-barcode.pro`, each in different directories. I usually just try `find . -name somefilename` from `/usr/share` if I want to find the location of a file.